# Swift GeoFire Error Linker Error _OBJC_CLASS_$_GeoFire

Tags: swift, xcode, geofire

I can compile and build the apps probably until I add this 2 line of geofire code, I get the linker error

```
  let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("USER")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


  let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
}
```

I have been stuck in this error for couple hours. Still not sure what and how to solve. 
It is my Podfile

```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FirebaseCore’
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseStorage'
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
  pod 'Material'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'MapKitGoogleStyler'
  pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.6'
  pod 'MapboxDirections.swift', '~> 0.12'

  #Pods for App

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

And it is the Error I got from XCode

**Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GeoFire", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SecondMainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but I found out the answer by adding `pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git', :branch => 'mpmcdonald-use-community'` and it run prefectly.

[Reference Link from Github](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/69)